# C# Console Application in VS code not writing in Application Insight

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-application-insights

I am trying to log CustomEvents in Application insight using telemetry . The code is a C# Console application and using below code to log Custom Event in Application Insight.

```
TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
configuration.InstrumentationKey = "*************";
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
var properties = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "testKey1", "testVal1" }, { "testKey2", "testVal2" } };
telemetryClient.TrackEvent(EventName, properties);  
telemetryClient.Flush();
```

This code is working fine in Visual Studio 2022 and also logging values in App Insight . But  in VS Code it is not pushing any data in App Insight. I am not even getting and error messages in VS Code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, ***Application insights*** is not supported for **.NET console application**. It supports **NodeJS** projects only.

That is the reason it not able to send the telemetry information into azure application insights.

[image]

You have to use the Visual Studio for full .NET Project supports.